# Markov Chain Lumpability conditions not met but reduced state space transition probabilities are equal to the lumpability method for calculation.

Tags: markov-chains

I have a Markov chain with a state space $S$ and its transition probability matrix generated mathematically as $P$.
I have created another Markov chain with a reduced state space $S_r$ made by partitioning $S$. The transition of this reduced state space Markov chain is mathematically generated as $P_r$.

Using the ordinary lumpability described in [1], I have determined the matrix $V$ and $U$. The Markov chain is not meeting the conditions for lumpability in Theorem 6.3.4 if [1], since I'm getting $$ VUPV \ne PV.$$ However, I'm still getting the transition probability of the reduced Markov chain equal to the method to calculate transition probability matrix using the lumpability method, i.e $$P_r = UPV.$$

Currently I'm able to do this numerically, over multiple small examples and its been consistently giving the above results of $P_r = UPV$, despite $VUPV \ne PV$. I don't have a mathematical proof yet on why this result exists.

My questions are:

1. Does my reduced Markov chain still represent the original Markov chain because $P_r = UPV$, simply because I have some special structure to the original Markov chain?
2. Are there any literature references that allow for my result?

[1] Kemeny, J. G., & Snell, J. L. (1960). *Finite Markov Chains.* Van Nostrand.